# What happen if first rule of first iptable chain target is `RETURN`?

Tags: iptables, firewall

The article [Linux Firewall Tutorial: IPTables Tables, Chains, Rules Fundamentals](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/01/iptables-fundamentals/) define the `RETURN` target value as follow:

> **RETURN** – Firewall will stop executing the next set of rules in the
>   current chain for this packet. The control will be *returned to the
>   calling chain*.

### Question

I was discussing with a colleague on the **effect of a such a target's value has the first rule of the first chain**.

As there is no *calling chain*, **what would happen to the packet?** Would it be rejected or accepted?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You mean e.g.

```
iptables -F INPUT
iptables -I INPUT 1 -j RETURN
```

From `man iptables`:

> If [...] a rule in a built-in chain with target RETURN is matched, the
>   target specified by the chain policy determines the fate of the
>   packet.

The chain policy is set with `iptables -P`, and can be found at the beginning of the output of `iptables -L -n -v`, eg:

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP 32 packets, 6666 bytes)
```

which shows a policy of `DROP` on the `INPUT` chain.

Comment: What is the _target specified by the chain policy_ here?

Comment: Will the RETURN be equivalent to a `DROP` or a `ACCEPT`?

Comment: Neither.  As it says above, the `RETURN` will do nothing at all, and the chain policy will take over.  To find or set the chain policy, see my edit above.

Comment: This is the first answer I found that actually explains RETURN in a simple yet accurate manner. +1

Comment: Why, thank you, aggregate!  It's nice to know one's efforts are appreciated, and better yet, useful.